# Writing to Labels sequentially in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, text, label, sequential

Apologies, this is probably a very simple problem, due to me stumbling through basic without any tuition....

I am trying to display cells from an excel file in labels attached to a table.
I can manipulate the excel file OK and I can do it if I use text boxes.

For example, using text boxes (this is an extract):

```vb
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel   

Public Class Form1

    Dim APP As New Excel.Application
    Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim excelfilepath As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim n As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form7_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(excelfilepath & "mydata.xlsx")
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
        APP.Visible = False

        For n = 1 To 10
            Me.Controls("textbox" & n).Text = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, n),   Excel.Range).Value.ToString
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above works fine. However, if I substitute the textbox line in the for/next loop with:

```vb
Me.Controls("label" & n).Text = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, n - 1), Excel.Range).Value.ToString
```

I get an unhandled exception "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Writing to a single label, thus:

```vb
Label16.Text = DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, n - 1), Excel.Range).Value.ToString
```

works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For textboxes you are using `Cells(1, n)` but for labels `Cells(1, n - 1)`. Also, your single label test uses label # 16, while your `n` goes from 1 to 10. Check if you really have all the labels between `label1` and `label10`.

Comment: Visually, a TextBox with `.BorderStyle` set to `None` and `.ReadOnly` set to `True` is the same as a Label,* and it offers the user the ability to copy-n-paste the data. (*Same visually, but you'd have to handle sizing because the TextBox doesn't have the `.AutoSize` property.)

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion, there. I'd used different numbers for labels and boxes as that's how they appear on the form.  My point is, if I substitute the word "Label" for "Textbox", one works, the other fails. Should the command be exactly the same? In other  words, is it just a dodgy bit of maths I'm using to calculate  the value of n.

Comment: I've since checked my maths by using a msgbox and it's ok! My command still fails using an expression, but an absolute reference, e.g 'Label9.Text' will work.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I will take the advice and go for textboxes, as I can get that working ok!

Comment: Your labels in your form should be named label1 to label10, because that's what's in your loop. Are these labels contained in another container, a panel, a groupbox? If so, you should use <Name of Container>.Controls("label" & n) instead of Me.Controls("label" & n). Also, excel rows and columns indexing start from 1 not 0. So this will produce an error `DirectCast(worksheet.Cells(1, n - 1), Excel.Range).Value.ToString` if n is 1

Comment: You can rename your labels so that they match the textbox names. Also, any label numbering math must be done in `Controls("label" & (n + offset)).Text` and does not affect the `Cells` numbering.